# Can't seem to upgrade from Ubuntu LTS 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I used DigitalOceans's instructions to try and upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 at [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts).

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for charlie: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [836 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,265 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,266 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'xenial.tar.gz' against 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'xenial.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Err http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en                        

Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Err http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en                        

Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
Err http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en                        

Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Err http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en                        

Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            

Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            

Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Err http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            

Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        

Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        

Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found                                                               
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found                                                               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found                                                               
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found                                                               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 0 B in 6s (31.4 MB/s)                                                  
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security InRelease                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial InRelease                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates InRelease                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/main Sources                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe Sources                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner Sources                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com xenial-security/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/restricted Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial-backports/universe Translation-en      
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
```

I believe that I need 16.04 to be able to run Devinci Resolve 12.5, so that's my current end game.

If anyone can make heads or tails of what I've sent or maybe tell me what else I can send to clarify, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pastebin that output and remove all the unnecessary information from your question =)

Comment: Davinci Resolve is a windows only application. This means it needs to be run in wine  or a virtual machine. WineHQ  currently list DaVinci Resolve12.5 as not runnable under Wine ver 1.9. Either version of ubuntu can  run a virtual machine with windows installed. (Note: a virtual machine requires a windows licence)

Comment: @ravery DaVinci Resolve has a Linux version. See the "Download" link on the [official page](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/).

Comment: Disable all external repos / ppa prior to your upgrade and use only the official ubuntu repositories.